# T4 template ignores extension attribute

Tags: t4

In my VS 2013 project, I added a T4 template file named `Foo.tt`, here is its contents:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".config"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
```

Each time I save the `.tt` file, or right-click on selected `Run Custom Tool`, the outputted file is `Foo.cs`, and not `Foo.config` as I was expecting.

Why is the .config extension attribute not being used?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted a “Text Template”, but created a “Runtime Text Template”. The latter will always create code which of course is `.cs`.

There are two kind of T4 templates:

- “Text Template”: `.tt` --> file.
- “Runtime Text Template”: `.tt` --> code (i.e. `.cs`) that can be used *at runtime* to obtain a string created from the template text.

And the latter [ignores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586943.aspx) `output extension`.

Comment: I checked the "Custom Tool" value of the .tt file and it's set to "TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor", if that helps at all.

Comment: It should be “TextTemplatingFileGenerator”.

Comment: Cool. I will give that a go next, when I'm back in the office.